# AWS Cloud watch event scheduler stopped triggering lambda

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch-events

i have "StartScheduledEvent" in yaml file , which triggers lambda for every 2 minutes. it stopped working and not sure sure why it stopped working.

I dont see any thing specific to it in lambda logs.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You should check your CloudTrail logs (the first trail is free) to see if there was any change to your schedule or lambda. It's abnormal for cloudwatch events scheduler to stop without reason. Sometimes, it can be as simple as missing permissions.

If you are unable to figure it out; you should file a support ticket with AWS to help debug this further.

There are also some instructions for specific issues in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eventbridge-troubleshooting.html